# trying to webscrape date of last document on a webpage in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the date as below : 01/19/2021, I would like to get the "19" in a python variable

```
<span class="grayItalic">
    Received: 01/19/2021
</span>
```

here is the piece of code unworking :

```
date = soup.find('span', {'class': 'grayItalic'}).get_text()
converted_date = int(date[13:14])
print(date)
```

I get this error : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
anyone could help ?

Comment: I bet the part you're scraping is generated dynamically by `JS` that's why you're getting the error. There's no such object in the `HTML` you have.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share the source url.

Comment: thank you for your reponse. Here is the url : https://iapps.courts.state.ny.us/nyscef/DocumentList?docketId=npvulMdOYzFDYIAomW_PLUS_elw==&PageNum=2&narrow=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with headers:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://iapps.courts.state.ny.us/nyscef/DocumentList?docketId=npvulMdOYzFDYIAomW_PLUS_elw==&display=all"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
date = soup.find('span', {'class': 'grayItalic'}).get_text().strip()
converted_date = int(date.split("/")[-2])
print(converted_date)
print(date)
```

Comment: thanks but didnt work. Seems like lxml is not in beautifulsoup

Comment: yes I put my headers, however the answer above is the actual issue. Seems like the website doesnt accept requests from programs

Comment: no, it works . You should use random user agent or headers.

Comment: I get this error message : bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Comment: indeed just did that and it worked, thanks a lot !

Comment: I tried couple of times and found it working always. It also works if you use `html.parser` instead of `lxml`. I suppose OP should not encounter any issue running the script now.

Comment: I dont know why but when I try to do this with page 2 (https://iapps.courts.state.ny.us/nyscef/DocumentList?docketId=npvulMdOYzFDYIAomW_PLUS_elw==&PageNum=2)  I get this error again :'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't load the URL using the request or urllib module. I guess the website is blocking automatic connection requests. So I opened the webpage and save the source code in a file name `page.html` and ran the `BeautifulSoup` operation in it. And it seems that worked.

```
html = open("page.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
date_span = soup.find('span', {'class': 'grayItalic'})

if date_span is not None:
    print(str(date_span.text).strip().replace("Received: ", ""))
    # output: 04/25/2019
```

I tried scraping the source code with the request library as follows but it didn't work (probably the webpage is blocking the request). See if it works on your machine.

```
url = "..."
headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
html = response.content

print(html)
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right, doesnt work for me either.Do you know if there anyway to bypass this ? Maybe in another langage like javascript or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

```
import dateutil.parser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc=""""<span class="grayItalic">
    Received: 01/19/2021
</span>"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html_doc,'html.parser')

date_ = soup.find('span', {'class': 'grayItalic'}).get_text()

dateutil.parser.parse(date_,fuzzy=True)
```

Output:

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 19, 0, 0)
```

`date_` outputs `'\n   Received: 01/19/2021\n'` You've string slicing ,instead you can use [`\[dateutil.parser\]`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html). Which will return a datetime.datetime object  for you.
In this case i've assumed you just need the date.If at all you need the text too,you can use `fuzzy_with_tokens=True`.

```
 if the fuzzy_with_tokens option is True, returns a tuple, the first element being a datetime.datetime object, the second a tuple containing the fuzzy tokens.
```

`dateutil.parser.parse(date_,fuzzy_with_tokens=True)`

`(datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 19, 0, 0), ('     Received: ', ' '))`

Comment: thanks, however I am a beginner at programmation and I didnt quite understand everything :p

Comment: btw don't use `date` as a variable